# RelativeLayout onClick fails to get triggered when EditText is embedded inside

Tags: android, user-interface, event-handling

#### Expected Result

There is a search bar implemented using a `EditText` inside a `RelativeLayout`. For some reason, the query to be searched is not going to be inputted into the `EditText` direct, but instead, on clicking the search bar, a WebView is triggered and load a search page where the user can input their search query there.

#### Problem

Set `android:onClick="selectCellSearch"` to `RelativeLayout`, click on the `EditText` the `selectCellSearch` callback function given by `onClick` seems not to be triggered.

#### Source Code

**`layout.xml`**

```
<!-- Start of Search Bar Cell -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="87dp"
    android:background="#212121"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="selectCellSearch"
    android:tag="search" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text_search_id"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_text_search_id"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:inputType="none" />

</RelativeLayout>
<!-- End of Search Bar Cell -->
```

#### Notes

The `android:tag="search"` is used for the URL generation of the search page to be loaded after clicking on the search bar, say, `http://mywebsite.com/search`.

#### Update

The `selectCellSearch()` is now posted here.

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
public void selectCellSearch(View view) {
    final String tag = (String) view.getTag();
    if (tag != null) {
        buttonForWebViewSlideInAnimation.performClick();
        mWebView.loadUrl(WEB_BASE_URI + tag);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your selectCellSearch() code ?

Comment: `selectCellSearch()` has been posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it's not advisable use the xml attribute onClick to set the onClickListener. Use the setOnClickListener method to do that always.

Second, the EditTest occupy all the size of the relative layout and is "over the relative". This situation produces that the onClick of the RelativeLayout never called.

To receive the click you can:

- Are you sure that the RelativeLayout is totally neccesary?
- You can set the onClick on the EditText
- Override the onInterceptTouchEvent or dispatchTouchEvent on your RelativeLayout. This methods will received the touch events (all, care about this!)

Comment: Does the `RelativeLayout` receive the touch event earlier than the `EditText`?

Comment: There are no "earlier". If you Ask, the methods onIntercep and onDispach receive the touch before the editText

Comment: It works by creating a customized layout, setting the return value as true for the overridden dispatchTouchEvent().

Answer (score 1):

Try `android:duplicateParentState="true"` in EditText